# C Threaded while loop not running

Tags: c, pthreads

I want a threaded `while` loop that forever increments `i`. Why does it stop prematurely?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *increment () {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        i++;
        printf("Number: %d", i);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid params\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t thread[num_threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &increment, argv[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to wait on the threads to finish before returning from main.  check out `pthread_join`

Comment: Also, your function `increment` is not declared properly.  It should be `void *increment(void *arg);`  Are you not getting compiler warnings?

Comment: Expanding on the comment from @MFisherKDX: Exiting or killing the process should kill all running threads.

Comment: `increment` is missing a `return NULL`.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Thank you for the help, i managed to get it to work. Sorry for my late reply

Comment: 'you do not need to wait on the threads to finish before returning from main, but if you do not wish the process to terminate quickly, you should prevent main() from returning. An input call, or sleep, or event wait would do.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "Invalid params\n");`   the preferred method is to tell the user what the program is expecting, as in: `fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s NumThreads\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &increment, argv[1]);`  Always check (==0) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `pthread` functions do not set `errno` so cannot use `perror()` nor `strerror()` to display why the error occurred.  Note: OS's have a limit (usually a rather small number) of threads that a process is allowed to have so if a large number is passed, the call to `pthread_create()` will soon start failing

Comment: OT: regarding: `void *increment () {`  a thread function has the signature: `void * mythreadname( void * arg )`  so your compiler should be warning about this mismatched signature

Answer (score 3):

just put

```
while(1);
```

before the return in main if you just want the created thread to run forever

E.g.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid params\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t thread[num_threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &increment, argv[1]);
    }

    while(1) ; // don't exit the main thread

    // while (1) sleep(1000) ; // would be better

    return 0;
}
```